# Railscast 153 revised: setting a background image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I'm trying to generate a PDF following the instructions given in http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised

I'm able to put a background image on a specific page by doing this:

```
image "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/document_assets/1_cover.png", :at => [bounds.left - 30, bounds.top + 50], :fit => [@width, @height]
```

I also got an image to render on the background of multiple pages at once using:

```
repeat(2..3) { canvas { image("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/document_assets/1_bg.png", :at => bounds.top_left, :fit => [@width, @height]) } }
```

but that renders the image on top of everything else on the page, so no text or other content is visible.

I can't seem to figure out how to set the background image property as described in the Prawn documentation.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  You can set the background option in the PDF class where the margins get set in the railscast example.  My issue was that the image I was using was not the right size.  When I sized it to 8.5x11" and 72px per inch, it worked.